# reCaptcha - fail of validation

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I'm using reCaptcha on my website and everything working fine at home but when I try it at work its only load reCaptcha but doesn't go through validation on submit button click (don't do anything on button click)!

I'm using this code for validation:

```
    function validateRecaptcha() {
        alert('inside validation');
        var challenge = Recaptcha.get_challenge();
        var response = Recaptcha.get_response();
        var remoteip = "<%=remoteip%>";


        alert('challenge - '+challenge);
        alert('response - '+response);
        alert('remoteip - '+remoteip);

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "validateRecaptcha.jsp",
          async: false,
          data: {
            remoteip: remoteip,
            challenge: challenge,
            response: response
          },
          success: function(resp) {
                if($.trim(resp) == "true") {
                    alert('captcha - right');
                    document.myform.submit();

                }
                else {
                    alert('captcha - wrong');
                    reloadRecaptcha();
                    enableWarningRecaptcha('Word Verification:',  '.warning', '.WordVerification');
                    return false;
                }
          }

        });
        alert('end of validation');
        return false;
    }
```

Also I'm using alerts functions for test purposes and these are test results:

- alert('inside validation'); - **fine**
- alert('challenge - '+challenge); - **fine**
- alert('response - '+response); - **fine**
- alert('remoteip - '+remoteip); - **fine**
- alert('captcha - right'); - **failed**
- alert('captcha - wrong'); - **failed**
- alert('end of validation'); - **fine**

**validateRecaptcha.jsp:**

```
<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaImpl,net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaResponse" %>
<%
ReCaptchaImpl reCaptcha = new ReCaptchaImpl();
reCaptcha.setPrivateKey("6LcMh-oSAAAAAF8m92XWQ4d2giKMIESghMQDQyQZ");

String remoteip = request.getParameter("remoteip");
String challenge = request.getParameter("challenge");
String res = request.getParameter("response");
ReCaptchaResponse reCaptchaResponse = reCaptcha.checkAnswer(remoteip, challenge, res);

if (reCaptchaResponse.isValid()) {
  out.print("true");
} else {
  out.print("false");
}
%>
```

May be its network problem??or something else?

Could anyone help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($.trim(resp) == "true") {
   alert('captcha - right');    
   document.myform.submit();
} else {
   alert('captcha - wrong');
   reloadRecaptcha();
   enableWarningRecaptcha('Word Verification:','.warning','.WordVerification');
   return false;
}
```

As you are submitting the form then making the alert so alert will not be see.

And to debug add the alert in the success function to check whether it is coming there or not.

Also add the error function in ajax:

```
error: function(ex,a,b,c){
  alert("some error");
}
```

Add this after the success function to debug is it have any error or not.

> Note: you can use the firebug also to check the status of your ajax
>   code.

Comment: It's - **Internal Server Error [500]**. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @DenissMuntjans may the given url in the ajax is not working right. check the permission and try by hitting the url in browser.

Comment: Problem is here (validateRecaptcha.jsp:) - `ReCaptchaResponse reCaptchaResponse = reCaptcha.checkAnswer(remoteip, challenge, res);` - **java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect**

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a firewall issue!

Comment: I switched Firewall off but this the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of that annoying Captcha garbage because JavaScript already provides a mechanism for determining if an event was user initiated via the "isTrusted" boolean property.

Usage is as follows...

```
<button id="logon" onclick="if(event.isTrusted){SomeFunction();}">Logon</button>
```

Any javascript attempt to click this button such as logon.click(); would fail this test and the function will not run.

Comment: Not helpful to the poster. Also, any program trying to access this human-only resource could just use a non-spec-compliant JS API such as JSDOM to simulate a trusted event programatically.